# hibernate connection pool

Tags: hibernate, connection-pooling, c3p0

I can't seem to get hibernate to use c3p0 for connection pooling, it says

```
12:30:35,038  INFO DriverManagerConnectionProvider:64 - Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
12:30:35,038  INFO DriverManagerConnectionProvider:65 - Hibernate connection pool size: 20
```

Hibernate Config:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxx?autoReconnect=true</property>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password">xxxx</property>
      <property name="show_sql">false</property>
      <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">200</property>
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">200</property>
      <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
  "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <!-- datasource config -->
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;autoReconnect=true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

        <property name="connection.username">user</property>
        <property name="connection.password">pass</property>

        <!-- c3p0 config http://www.hibernate.org/214.html -->
        <property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>        
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">60</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">2</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">0</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryDelay">250</property>

        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</property>

        <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        ...

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: It is important to select the proper connection.provider_class.

Comment: `org.hibernate.connection.C3P0` has been deprecated in favor of `org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider`.

Comment: Thanks @lserni for mentioning, I haven't been up to date with hibernate for the last two years.

Comment: @lserni guess it is a change with hibernate 4?  Anyway some other notes: you don't "have" to specify the provider_class as long as you specify "some" c3p0 settings it seems to use it, though it's probably better to call it out explicitly.

Comment: I thought idle_test_period value must never exceed that of timeout.

Answer (score -3):

The best way to resolve these DTD (Document Type Definition) mappings issues is to

1. Take the hibernate jar file and unzip/jar and get the two files -
   hibernate-configuration dtd file and hibernate-mapping dtd file.
2. Copy the DTD declaration from these two files and  use them in your
   cfg.xml and hbm.xml respectively.

Comment: This is not related to the problem in the question.