# Hibernate production use warning

Tags: java, database, eclipse, hibernate, oracle11g

This warning comes up evertime i use hibernate.

```
Mai 11, 2015 3:42:20 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
```

Do i have to be worried about this?
The tables are created without problem, but this warning makes me unsure about my hibernate.cfg.xml configuration file.

Thx in advance for your support.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hibernate connection pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067526/hibernate-connection-pool)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in hibernate connection pool is not suitable for large scale production use (for this read many clients). So you probably don't want to use it to service a lot of users. Luckily, there are a huge number of java connection pools to choose from:

http://www.codecommit.com/blog/java/wide-world-of-pool-providers-side-by-side-comparison