# c3p0 connection pooling library with Hibernate 3.2.6/JPA - Cannot open connection

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, c3p0

My application have two quartz jobs readning two different tables from Oracle DB in the same time.
I am trying to get a connection from pool using c3p0 with Hibernate and Oracle. When Tomcat 7 starts it seems like C3P0 is initialized:

> 2021-02-15 18:47:26,271 [INFO] Hibernate EntityManager 3.2.1.GA 
> 2021-02-15 18:47:26,290 [INFO] Hibernate Annotations 3.2.1.GA 
> 2021-02-15 18:47:26,299 [INFO] Hibernate 3.2.6
>  ... 
>  2021-02-15
> 18:47:27,473 [INFO] Initializing c3p0-0.9.1 [built 16-January-2007
> 14:46:42; debug? true; trace: 10] 
>  2021-02-15 18:47:27,621 [INFO]
> Initializing c3p0 pool...
> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolBackedDataSource@add8f7b3 [
> connectionPoolDataSource ->
> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource@e6d03554 [
> acquireIncrement -> 1, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay
> -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, ... ]
>
> 2021-02-15 18:47:28,240 [INFO] RDBMS: Oracle, version: Oracle Database
> 11g Release 11.1.0.0.0 - Production 
>  2021-02-15 18:47:28,241
> [INFO] JDBC driver: Oracle JDBC driver, version: 10.2.0.4.0 
> 2021-02-15 18:47:28,280 [INFO] Using dialect:
> org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect

But after a few lines, it is still showing Hibernate built-in connection pool, I don't know if that's the way it should be? :

> 2021-02-15 18:47:37,726 [INFO] Using Hibernate built-in connection
> pool (not for production use!)
>  2021-02-15 18:47:37,726 [INFO]
> Hibernate connection pool size: 20

Anyway, after first job successful got data from Oracle DB, second job could not obtain a connection from pool because it is closed:

> 2021-02-15 18:48:38,923 [WARN] SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null 
> 2021-02-15 18:48:38,923 [ERROR] com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolBackedDataSource@add8f7b3
> [ connectionPoolDataSource ->
> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource@e6d03554 [
> acquireIncrement -> 1, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay
> -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0,
> connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName ->
> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester,
> debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, factoryClassLocation ->
> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken ->
> 2zgg5baf1aa5t7d1frz5fs|700f6fc5, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 3000,
> initialPoolSize -> 10, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0,
> maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 300,
> maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 20, maxStatements ->
> 50, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 10,
> nestedDataSource ->
> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource@2f7ccb64 [ description ->
> null, driverClass -> null, factoryClassLocation -> null, identityToken
> -> 2zgg5baf1aa5t7d1frz5fs|6a16a596, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.129.12.158:1520:orcl, properties -> {user=******,
> password=******, autocommit=true, release_mode=auto} ],
> preferredTestQuery -> null, propertyCycle -> 0,
> testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false,
> unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies ->
> false; userOverrides: {} ], dataSourceName -> null,
> factoryClassLocation -> null, identityToken ->
> 2zgg5baf1aa5t7d1frz5fs|63308385, numHelperThreads -> 3 ] **has been
> closed() -- you can no longer use it.** 
> 2021-02-15 18:48:38,923 [DEBUG] [docadmin] ccmwsWebQuartz::GenerateDocumentTypeOfRequestJob.generateDocumentTypeOfRequest() - errororg.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
> 2021-02-15 18:48:38,923 [DEBUG] ccmwsWebQuartz::GenerateDocumentTypeOfRequestJob.generateRequest(): exception: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection 1613411318923 ms.
> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
> at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:629)
> at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:73)
> at com.ct.contentintegration.scheduler.GenerateDocumentTypeOfRequestJob.generateDocumentTypeOfRequest(GenerateDocumentTypeOfRequestJob.java:165)
> at com.ct.contentintegration.scheduler.GenerateDocumentTypeOfRequestJob.generateRequest(GenerateDocumentTypeOfRequestJob.java:89)
> at com.ct.contentintegration.scheduler.GenerateDocumentTypeOfRequestScheduler.execute(GenerateDocumentTypeOfRequestScheduler.java:23)
> at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
> at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:529)
> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection

Configuration file look like this:
**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Persistence deployment descriptor for dev profile -->
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">
    
    <persistence-unit name="jpaCcmwsWebJob">

        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

<!--                        RAZVOJ                               -->

        <properties>

            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.129.12.158:1520:orcl" />

            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />

            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />

            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="docadmin2010" />

            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="docadmin" />

            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            

            
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="10" />
          <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20" />
          <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300" />
          <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
          <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />
          <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="3000" />

        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Oracle connection type is **Basic**.

Any ideas what I was doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

That's an old hibernate version.

Which are your dependencies for hibernate-c3p0 and c3p0?

Checking from another post, it seems that the connection provider class for c3p0 was
`org.hibernate.connection.C3P0` but was deprecated later for `org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider`.

Maybe based on your hibernate version you should try using the older connection provider class.

[hibernate connection pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067526/hibernate-connection-pool)

Comment: It's an old project still working in production.I have added c3p0-0.9.1.jar only, Don't have any other C3p0 related jars. Existing hibernate jars are: hibernate3.jar,  hibernate-annotations.jar, hibernate-commons-annotations-3.3.0.jar, hibernate-entitymanager.jar. Do I need to upgrade hibernate version in order to implement c3p0 connection pooling?

Comment: Try including a newer version of hibernate-c3p0 like 3.3.2.GA and setting the hibernate.connection.provider_class to org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider

Comment: I've included hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar and hibernate-c3p0-3.3.2.GA.jar instead of hibernate3.jar, but error is the same. Beside that connection.provider_class is not org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider because package in that version is org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider

Comment: If this runs once and then failes, can you add a sample of your code here to check

Comment: When I used hibernate built-in connection pool, (without any C3P0 jars) these two jobs worked fine several hours or even all day, but eventually got error SQL Error: 17008, SQLState: null, connection closed. That's why I thought the code was correct,  but I'll post it later laptop battery is empty :-) and there is no power supply.